# Python: Identify breaking points in a data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, grouping, intervals

I am interested in identifying when different trips take place in a dataset. There are two lock states, where *lock* means the vehicle is stationary and *unlocked* means that the vehicle is being used.

As the same vehicle could be used by the same user multiple times, I first isolate the vehicle and a unique user through IDs and from a **chronologically sorted** time date column I can see when the vehicle was used. In order to **identify different trips** taken in the same vehicle by the same user I thought of identifying through my lock_state variable.

I've been trying to find how this could be done and **percolation** is something I came across but it seems too complex to understand and implement. I was wondering if there is an easier way of achieving this.

My end goal is to identify the number of trips (should be 2 in this example), add them to a new df alongside the user id and start/end datetimes (let's pretend all of this is the random column) and give them unique IDs. So the final output should be something like this (random made-up example):

```
trip_id      star_time  end_time user_id
jk3b4334kjh  x           x       093723
nbnmvn829nk  x           x       234380
```

Assuming the following sample data is in chronological order, how could I identify through the variable *state* different trips? (there should be 2 trips identified as the array is under continuous "unlocked" state twice before being interrupted by a "locked" state).

```
lock_state = ["locked", "unlocked", "unlocked", "unlocked", "locked", "locked", "unlocked", "unlocked"]
# should be 2 trips

random_values = random.sample(range(2,20), 8) 

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'state': lock_state,
     'random': random_values
    })

df

>>
    state   random
0   locked      5
1   unlocked    12
2   unlocked    17
3   unlocked    13
4   locked      18
5   locked      6
6   unlocked    4
7   unlocked    9
```

Comment: Clearly, you can iterate through the rows, watch for state changes, and record the info at the transitions.  Are you looking for something more automatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this implementation of a 1D Hoshen-Kopelman cluster labelling.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lock_state = ["locked", "unlocked", "unlocked", "unlocked", "locked", "locked", "unlocked", "unlocked"]

random_values = random.sample(range(2,20), 8) 

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'state': lock_state,
     'random': random_values
    })
    

def hoshen_kopelman_1d(grid, occupied_label):
    """
    Hoshen Kopelman implementation for 1D graphs.
    
    Parameters:
            grid (pd.DataFrame): The 1D grid. 
            ocuppied_label (str): the label that identifies occupied nodes.

    Returns:
            labeled_grid (pd.DataFrame): grid with cluster labeled nodes.
    """
    
    # create labeled_grid and assign all nodes to cluster 0
    labeled_grid = df.assign(cluster=0)
    cluster_count = 0
    
    # iterate through the grid's nodes left to right
    for index, node in grid.iterrows():
        # check if node is occupied
        if node["state"] == occupied_label: # node is occupied
            if index == 0:
                # initialize new cluster
                cluster_count += 1
                labeled_grid.loc[0, "cluster"] = cluster_count
            else:
                # check if left-neighbour node is occupied
                if labeled_grid.loc[index-1, "cluster"] != 0: # left-neighbour node is occupied
                    # assign node to the same cluster as left-neighbour node
                    labeled_grid.loc[index, "cluster"] = labeled_grid.loc[index-1, "cluster"]
                else: # left-neighbour node is unoccupied
                    # initialize new cluster
                    cluster_count += 1
                    labeled_grid.loc[index, "cluster"] = cluster_count
                    
    return labeled_grid
                

M = hoshen_kopelman_1d(grid=df, occupied_label="unlocked")
```

It returns a new `pandas.DataFrame` with an extra `"cluster"` column, which indicates the cluster to which the node belongs (`0` means the node is unoccupied and does not belong to any cluster).

Having this, it becomes pretty straightforward to retrieve the rows from, e.g., trip `1`. We could do

```
trip_1 = M.loc[M['cluster'] == 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`shift` your `state` column by 1 row; compare against the original, and filter on state "unlocked".  Those identifies runs of consecutive "unlocked" states.  The shift-compare portion is

```
df.state.eq(df.state.shift())
```

Given that hint, I expect that you can finish the coding, eh?